# Maps API savedata function if statement ignored

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an issue with savedata... It saves the data to the database, and it also shows it on the map, so basically everything is working, but when I save the address and name of the marker and then click on the save button I can't close it...

```
downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
  infowindow.close();
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
}
```

There's something bad starting from downloadUrl, it seems that code is just ignored, therefore I put an alert to let the user know that it is saved.

I copy the whole javascript if it helps(it also includes geocoder and styled map) :
If You want I can give you a link to the map or anything You need.

```
var marker;
var infowindow;
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var styles = [
{
  "stylers": [
  { "hue": "#0055ff" },
  { "saturation": 90 },
  { "gamma": 0.39 },
  { "lightness": 48 },
  { "visibility": "on" },
  { "invert_lightness": true }
 ]
 },{
"featureType": "road",
"stylers": [
  { "hue": "#ff4500" }
]
},{
"elementType": "labels",
"stylers": [
  { "hue": "#00ff6f" },
  { "gamma": 6.31 },
  { "weight": 0.2 }
]
}
];

var SajatMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
{name: "Saját Map"});


  var image=new google.maps.MarkerImage('resistance2.png',
  new google.maps.Size(23, 30),
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 32));

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.495632, 19.044748);
    var options = {
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'sajat_map']
      }
    };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

map.mapTypes.set('sajat_map', SajatMap);
map.setMapTypeId('sajat_map');

var html = "<table>" +
             "<tr><td>Név:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Hely:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td></td><td><input id='save' type='button' value='Mentés'    onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: html
});


google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});

  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon:image,
        position: point
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });     
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

  function saveData() {
  var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
  var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
  var latlng = marker.getPosition();

  var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
            "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
            alert('Successfully saved!');
  downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
      infowindow.close();
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
    }
  });
 }

function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById("kereso").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Sikertelen. A probléma oka: " + status);
  }
});
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Comment: I don't know Google Maps API very well, but what is the `data.length <= 1` condition? Why do you want to check for 1-character or 0-character length messages?

Comment: Do you actually mean `data.length >= 1`, or does the presence of more than one character of data indicate an error of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is old but I came searching for the same problem, and I found the answer, so it might help others.

Your code probably comes from https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

There it says as an explanation for the use of `if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1)`:

- *Check that the returned status code is 200. This means that the file was retrieved successfully and we can continue processing.*
- *Check the length of the data string returned - an empty data file indicates that the request generated no error strings. If the length is zero, you can close the info window and output a success message.*

If you log `data` from `downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {` you will see they made a mistake there:

Logging the `data` object shows: `XMLHttpRequest {statusText: "OK", status: 200, response: "", responseType: "", responseXML: null…}`

It seems to me that they meant `response: ""`: if there is an error, it would go in there. Hence, if `data.response.length < 1`, it means there is no error.

I'm quite new to Javascript so correct me if wrong but this did it for me:

```
  downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.response.length <= 1) {
      infowindow.close();
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have the same problem... I changed the "data.response.length" but it did no difference. I removed it and it worked. or if I change it to data.length > 1 See next answer.

Answer (score 2):

You say that the dialog doesn't close, which suggests to me that the condition

```
responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1
```

is coming up `false`.

This is probably because the response you get back from the server has more than one character, so `data.length <= 1` is `false` (because that condition is `true` only for messages with one, zero, or negative lengths). Verify that your responses have at most one byte of content.

Perhaps you actually meant to test for non-empty messages, i.e., `data.length >= 1`. Right now you allow the close only on responses that are one byte *or shorter*; I am guessing that you really wanted to allow a close on message that are one byte *or longer*

Comment: I set it to data.length >= 1 now, but it's just not working, so I removed it and I left respsonceCode == 200 only and now it closes the window.